# Aes encryption on Android(client) and Decryption on Server with C++

Tags: java, c++, openssl, aes

I am working with AES encryption on my android application and I have a problem. I want my application to encrypt a password using Aes_256_Cbc algorithm. The encrypted string must be different each time that's why I need a truly random iv each time. The code I have to encrypt the word is:

```java
import android.content.Context;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Encryptor
{
Context context;
private static final String WORD = "aefbjolpigrschnx";
private static final String KEY = "kumyntbrvecwxasqertyplmqazwsxedc";
private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";


public Encryptor(Context c)
{
    context = c;
}

public String getEncryptedPasswd()
{
    String ivHex = "";
    String encryptedHex = "";

    try 
    {
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        ivHex = toHex(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");


        Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC");
        encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);
        byte[] encryptedText = encryptionCipher.doFinal(WORD.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        encryptedHex = toHex(encryptedText);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }
    return ivHex + encryptedHex;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) 
{
    if (buf == null)
    {
        return "";
    }       
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
    {
            result.append(HEX.charAt((buf[i]>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(buf[i]&0x0f));

    }
    return result.toString();

}
```

My application calls the function `getEncryptedPasswd()` several times, each time it gives a different hex output, as expected. Then it sends the encrypted password to the server where my code must be in C++. But when I try to decrypt the password using openssl I don't take the correct output. Can anyone help me? My code at the server is:

```cs
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

#define KEY "kumyntbrvecwxasqertyplmqazwsxedc"

using namespace std;

unsigned int hex2bin(char *ibuf, unsigned char *obuf, unsigned int ilen)
{
unsigned int i;
unsigned int j;
unsigned int by = 0;
unsigned char ch;

// process the list of characaters
for (i = 0; i < ilen; i++)
{
        ch = toupper(*ibuf++);
    // do the conversion
        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    {
        by = (by << 4) + ch - '0';
    }    
    else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
    {
            by = (by << 4) + ch - 'A' + 10;
    }
        else
    {
        memcpy(obuf, "ERROR", 5);
            return 0;
        }

        // store a byte for each pair of hexadecimal digits
        if (i & 1) 
    {
            j = ((i + 1) / 2) - 1;
            obuf[j] = by & 0xff;
        }
}
return (j+1);
}

string iv_str = auth.substr(0, 16);
string enc_str = auth.substr(16);

char *iv_buf = new char [iv_str.length() + 1];
strcpy(iv_buf, iv_str.data());
char *enc_buf = new char [enc_str.length() + 1];
strcpy(enc_buf, enc_str.data());

unsigned long ilen;
unsigned char iv[16];
unsigned char enc_word[16]; // hex decrypt output
unsigned char word[16]; // decrypt output
unsigned char enc_key[] = KEY;
AES_KEY aeskeyDec;

    AES_set_decrypt_key(enc_key, 256, &aeskeyDec);

    ilen = hex2bin(enc_buf, enc_word, (int) strlen(enc_buf));
hex2bin(iv_buf, iv, (int) strlen(iv_buf));

    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_word, word, ilen, &aeskeyDec, iv, AES_DECRYPT);
```

Comment: One possible difference might be padding? You've not chosen a padding option in the Java code. I'm not sure if it defaults to `NoPadding` or `PKCS5Padding`. It's plausible the C++ code uses something else? Is your output completely incorrect or does it just contain unexpected characters?

Comment: Also, have you completed a test to ensure your Java and C++ hex encoding/decoding methods are compatible? If you've made a mistake in one of the implementations, you may be operating on false data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is completely incorrect. My suspicion is that the c++ code has the problem and not the android(java) one. Is there a standard aes implementation in C++ of how to decrypt a hex string encrypted in Java(android)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C++ guy, not java, so I cannot comment on this line of yours other than to say that it looks like it would do what you need:

```
Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC");
```

But just in case there is more to it, note that I can confirm that Java by default uses ECB mode.  Like yourself, I also had to AES decrypt in C++ some text that had been encrypted in Java.  Took me a while to figure out what was happening:  [how to use OpenSSL to decrypt Java AES-encrypted data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136279/how-to-use-openssl-to-decrypt-java-aes-encrypted-data)