# Set padding in OpenSSL for AES_ecb_encrypt

Tags: cryptography, openssl, aes, pkcs#5

I'm decrypting some java encrypted text with OpenSSL. Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136279/how-to-use-openssl-to-decrypt-java-aes-encrypted-data) I wrote the following code.

```
unsigned int i = 0;
printf("Out array - Before\n");
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(out); i++) {
    if(i % 32 == 0)
        printf("\n");
    printf("%02X", out[i]);
}
printf("\n");

AES_set_decrypt_key((const unsigned char *)a.at(3).c_str(), 128, &aesKey_);
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(bytes); i += AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
    std::cout << "Decrypting at " << i << " of " << sizeof(bytes) << "\n";
    AES_ecb_encrypt(bytes + i, out + i, &aesKey_, AES_DECRYPT);
}

std::cout << "HEX        : " << a.at(2).c_str() << "\n"
<< "Decrypting : " << bytes << "\n"
<< "With Key   : " << a.at(3).c_str() << "\n"
<< "Becomes    : " << out << "\n";

printf("Out array - AFTER\n");
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(out); i++) {
    if(i % 32 == 0)
        printf("\n");
    printf("%02X", out[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

It appears to decrypt the data fine, though the `PKCS5-padding` gets decrypted along and some extra garbage (I'm assuming this is due to the `PKCS5-padding`).

```
Out array - BEFORE 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Decrypting at 0 of 18
Decrypting at 16 of 18
HEX        : B00FE0383F2E3CBB95A5A28FA91923FA00
Decrypting : ��8?.<������#�
With Key   : I'm a secret key
Becomes    : no passwordHQ�EZ��-�=%.7�n
Out array - AFTER 6E6F2070617373776F72644851030303C7457F5ACCF12DAA053D252E3708846E
```

The above is output from my code, `no passwordHQ` (`6E6F2070617373776F72644851`) is the expected output, but you can see the padding is decoded `030303` followed by the garbage `C7457F5ACCF12DAA053D252E3708846E`.

So how do I set the padding in OpenSSL?

I expected there to be an `AES_set_padding` (or similar) function, but I'm obviously missing it in the documentation.

Comment: `AES_ecb_encrypt(bytes + i, out + i, &aesKey_, AES_DECRYPT);` This decrypts it. Note `AES_DECRYPT`

Comment: replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: @andrewcooke after all your help and your white space edits, we are no closer to answering the question. But thanks for your invaluable knowledge.

Comment: i would have helped, but i used up my spare time just sorting this mess out.  maybe next time...

Answer (score 0):

Please try and use the higher level function defined in [EVP_*](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html#). For those functions PKCS#7 padding is standard. Note that PKCS#5 padding officially is only [for 8 byte block ciphers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172).

After some searching I found that `evp.h` should contain:

```
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_aes_128_ecb(void);
```

which you should be able to use with

```
int EVP_EncryptInit(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const EVP_CIPHER *type,
     unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv);
```

additional information about EVP functions does suggest that it shoud automatically use the correct padding. The IV is of course ignored for ECB mode, so any pointer should do.

Comment: Thanks. I may be mistaken, but I cannot find an EVP function for AES EBC in the documentation. I have the same issue as the linked post, some legacy (java) code that needs supporting does it this way. I have moved all code to use AES CPC and do use the EVP functions without issue. It would appear that the java code is using PKCS#5 by default for AES ECB (128).

Comment: I'll have a look later on for the EVP functionality. By default Java uses "cipher/ECB/PKCS5Padding" in the Sun provider, but it is much better to explicitly define what mode of operation and padding mode should be used (no need for guessing). Especially since ECB mode is insecure.

Comment: Do you know if I can set a zero padding to EVP_EncryptInit_ex instead of PKCS padding?

Comment: You should be able to use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding` on the now initialized context.